# How to solve this limit using Taylor formula?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have difficulties in solving this limit using Taylor formula.

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow+ \infty} \big((x+a)^{1+\frac {1}{x}} - x^{1+\frac{1}{x+a}}\big) $$
Can you give me some advice? I will be very thankful for your help.

Comment: Using the "Taylor formula"  here is the same as using the binomial theorem:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = bx$,

$(x+a)^{1+\frac {1}{x}} - x^{1+\frac{1}{x+a}}=((b+1)x)^{1+\frac{1}{x}}-x^{1+\frac{1}{(1+b)x}}$

fixing $x$, expand at $b=0$

$x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}(1+b+o(b^2))-(x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}-\log(x)x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}\frac{1}{x}b+o(b^2))=x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}(1+\frac{\log(x)}{x})b+o(b^2)=ax^{\frac{1}{x}}(1+\frac{\log(x)}{x})+o(b^2)$

This converges to $a$ as $x\rightarrow\infty, b\rightarrow0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the generalized binomial theorem

$$(a+b)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}b+\frac {n(n-1)}{2!}a^{n-2}b^2+\ldots$$